# Eulerproject 2 Fibonacci calculation

Tags: python

I am as new as you can be to Python and trying to learn by following a few guides and doing little projects simultaneously.

I am currently trying to do the 2nd Eulerproject question regarding Fibonacci numbers. It goes as follows:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

And this was my attempt at solving it

```
Fib = [1, 2, 3]
answer_list = []

x = Fib[-1]
y = Fib[-2]

while x <= 4000000:
  z = x + y
  Fib.append(z)

for number in Fib:
  if number % 2 == 0:
    answer_list.append(number)

answer = sum(answer_list)

print(answer)
```

When I try to use this code I do not get a response. Can anyone, if possible without giving me the actual answer, point me in the right direction on how to improve?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: You don't ever change `x`, therefore you are stuck in the while loop. You probably want to do `x  = Fib[-1]` inside the `while`

Comment: @DavidG actually you solved my problem, thank you. I had to keep the line inside as well as outside the while loop because otherwise nothing is defining 'x' for the 'while' line itself, surely there is a more elegant way of phrasing this..

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler and faster way to do the same:

```
fib = [1, 1]  # something to start with
while fib[-1] < 4000000 :
    fib.append( fib[-1] + fib[-2] )
print sum( i for i in fib if i&1 == 0 )
```

outputs:

```
4613732
```

If the upper limit is much higher than 4e6, a better approach would be to avoid creating large lists and just use two variables `previous` and `current` for the Fibonacchi numbers generation, and one extra variable to keep the sum of the even elements. Something along the lines of:

```
>>> total = 0
>>> current = previous = 1
>>> while current < 4000000 :
...     if current & 1 == 0 : total += current
...     previous, current = current, previous + current
... 
>>> total
4613732
```

One extra word of the warning, the last number over 4e6 is 5702887 -- an odd number, so I did not care about removing it from the list in the first code sample. But if you want to be extra careful, add `fib.pop()` before summing the elements.